# Magento percentage discount amount/value being applied tax rule

Tags: magento-1.7, shopping-cart-price-rules, discount

I have strange behaviour which has always existed in my magento 1.7.0.2 as far as I am aware.

I have a tax rule of 20% for all products so prices are input without tax.

When creating a Percentage discount in Promotions > shopping cart price rules>

Under Actions tab I am choosing 'percentage of product price" option.

I am setting value to 7%.

When I use the coupon the discounted amount seems work out 20% more. E.g 7x1.2 = 8.2%

So for a real example I have a product with price 519. I apply 7% coupon and the final price  is 475.40.

519 to 475.40 is in fact a difference of 8.38%

This happens to all products with regular price and special prices.

I also have this issue with fixed price discounts.

If I want to have a discount of £5 I have to make the value in the shopping cart price rule 4.166. Is this normal behaviour for magento?

I could not find anyone posting about this exact issue anywhere. Maybe I am wording it wrong in my searches.

Now onto my tax settings in system>configuration>sales>tax

Please see image below.

[image]

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: I'm not sure it leads to a direct answer, but you say that your prices are input without tax (`I have a tax rule of 20% for all products so prices are input without tax.`), however `Calculation Settings > Catalog Prices` is set to `includes tax`, that doesn't sound right.

Comment: I just changed the setting to 'excludes tax' cleared cache reindexed I still seem to have the issue.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It sounds like your issue is that your discounts are applying to products that already have the 20% tax added to them. If this is the issue, you can solve it by changing your configuration:

`Calculation Settings`-> `Apply Discount on Prices`

Change `Including Tax` to `Excluding Tax`

Comment: Yes this worked. Now coupon percentage is applying correctly. I remember changing this setting a while back because for fixed price discounts in the checkout totals section the customer would see £4.166 in place of a £5 discount. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Happy to help! If this has solved your issue, please mark the answer as accepted so the site knows this question has been resolved. Cheers